# animate not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I just can't see something that must be obvious... just trying to animate a div... I got the jquery animate to work with just the number but I couldn't get it with the arrayIndex... the console.log called the number 40 in the array...

```
<div id="blueCar" > </div>

$( document ).ready(function() {    
var carArrayX = [765,650,460,330,140,40];
var carArrayY = [ 390,390,390,405,445,405];
var carArrayXindex = carArrayX.length -1;

    //$('#blueCar').animate({left:"40px"}); //works!
    //$('#blueCar').animate({left:"carArrayX[carArrayXindex]" + "px"});
    $('#blueCar').animate({left:"carArrayX[carArrayXindex] + px"});

    console.log(carArrayX[carArrayXindex]);
});
```

Comment: Try taking the array outside of the double quotes so it doesn't think its a string. $('#blueCar').animate({left:carArrayX[carArrayXindex] + "px"});

Comment: `$('#blueCar').animate({left:carArrayX[carArrayXindex] + "px"});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$('#blueCar').animate({left:"carArrayX[carArrayXindex] + px"});
```

to:

```
$('#blueCar').animate({left:carArrayX[carArrayXindex] + "px"});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/f3R8j/)**

You had the first quote in the wrong spot. You were passing a string instead of the variable value concatenated with "px".

Answer (score 0):

You are putting variable names in quotes. So the animate function is literally setting `left` to the string

```
"carArrayX[carArrayXIndex] + px"
```

You need to remove the quotes on the variable identifiers. Javascript is not PHP, you know, you can't just put variable names in strings and expect them to be replaced with the variable contents. Of course, the `px` which IS a string literal, still needs to be put in quotes. Try this code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
    var carArrayX = [765,650,460,330,140,40];
    var carArrayY = [ 390,390,390,405,445,405];
    var carArrayXindex = carArrayX.length -1;

    $('#blueCar').animate({left:carArrayX[carArrayXindex] + "px"});

    console.log(carArrayX[carArrayXindex]);
});
```

Comment: Also, try using an IDE with syntax highlighting. It will help you spot errors like this. Did you know eclipse has a javascript plugin?